# How to set style of a data layer feature label in Google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I've got this working js code:

```
var p;
p = new google.maps.Data();
p.loadGeoJson('http://mysource.example.com');
p.setStyle( function(feature){
    var icon = feature.getProperty('icon');
    var title = feature.getProperty('title');
    return  { 
        icon: icon,
        label: title
    }
});
p.setMap(map);
```

The code generate this output:

[image]:

How can I set the style of the label "L1PIAZZA"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the documented properties to style the [MarkerLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel):

> **Properties**
>
> **color** Type:  string
>
> The color of the label text. Default color is black.
>
> **fontFamily** Type:  string
>
> The font family of the label text (equivalent to the CSS font-family property).
>
> **fontSize** Type:  string
>
> The font size of the label text (equivalent to the CSS font-size property). Default size is 14px.
>
> **fontWeight** Type:  string
>
> The font weight of the label text (equivalent to the CSS font-weight property).
>
> **text** Type:  string
>
> The text to be displayed in the label.

```
p.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var icon = feature.getProperty('icon');
  var title = feature.getProperty('title');
  return {
    icon: {
      url: icon,
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15, -10)
    },
    label: {
      color: "blue",
      fontFamily: "Courier",
      fontSize: "24px",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      text: title
    }
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95yyzxhL/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting labelled marker on map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var p;
  p = new google.maps.Data();
  p.addGeoJson({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "icon": "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
        "title": "blue",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-122.1419, 37.4419]
      }
    }]
  });
  p.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var icon = feature.getProperty('icon');
    var title = feature.getProperty('title');
    return {
      icon: {
        url: icon,
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15, -10)
      },
      label: {
        color: "blue",
        fontFamily: "Courier",
        fontSize: "24px",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        text: title
      }
    }
  });
  p.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```